# Does system of cutting arcs generate $H_1(M,\partial M)$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $M$ be a connected, orientable manifold with boundary. Is it true that a set of properly immersed arcs that cut $M$ into a ball generates $H_1(M,\partial M, \mathbb{Z})$?

If so, are those generators linearly indipendent if the set of arc is minimal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must mean $M$ a surface, in which case yes (think about the polygonal representation of the closed surface and delete some well-chosen balls). For higher-dimensional $M$, deleting arcs will either (1) in 3D, make the fundamanetal group more complicated, or (2) in dimensions 4 and up, not change the fundamental group at all.

In particular you cannot possibly make $M$ simply connected by deleting arcs except in dimension 2.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I had the case of surfaces in mind and tried to write the question in a more general form (but that doesn't make much sense as you pointed out)

Comment: I wonder if in dimension $n$, one can find a system of some $(n-1)$-discs that cut the manifold into a disc.

Comment: @giulio I think maybe by considering a well-chosen triangulation, but I am not sure...

Comment: Ah, no, I don't think so. You want the discs to have boundary contained in the boundary, right? Then deleting a disc can only increase the number of boundary components. Dimension 2 is special because we use arcs and $\partial I = 0 \cup 1$ is disconnected.

Comment: Correct. But If we don't ask for the disc to have boundary in the boundary of the manifold I think we could do that. Take a handle decomposition and for each $k$-handle $D^k\times D^{n-k}$ remove the disc $D^{k-1}\times D^{n-k}$. The cut handle retracts to the boundary and we finally get a $0$-handle (assuming that the decomposition has only one 0-handle, but if the manifold is connected that's fine). Now, does it make sense to ask if these discs generate $H_{n-1}(M,\partial M)$?

Comment: But maybe i should post a new question

Comment: I'm guessing there is some Poincaré/Lefschetz duality involved

Comment: No, if the discs don't have boundary lying in $\partial M$, they do not give homology classes in $H_{n-1}(M, \partial M)$! @giulio. You can definitely make cuts along discs to turn the manifold into a ball (starting from a triangulation and deleting an appropriate collection of (n-1)-simplices) but the things you delete won't relate to the relative homology

Comment: You’re  right @kkotjon , bad mistake. I will try again: i claim that there is a collection of discs of different dimensions that together cut the manifold into a ball and that generate the whole homology of $(M,\partial M)$. Take $\partial M$ and attach handles to obtain M (in other words this is a handle decomposition for the cobordism (M,\partial M, \emptyset)$. Now the cores of the handles give you a set of generators for $H_*(M,\partial M)$. Reverse this handle decomposition and you have a decomposition for M. The roles of cores and cocores of the handles have exchanged so you may take

Comment: the cocores of the usual handle decomposition of M as generators for $H_*(M,\partial M)$. These cocores are properly embedded discs and cut the manifold into a disc.